# "Permission Denied" Errors Serving SVN/WebDAV to Mac OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, permissions, svn, webdav

I am setting up a server for a small office. Due to technical difficulties, they had files disappearing constantly. In order to prevent this, I am setting up Apache with Autoversioned Subversion over WebDAV. The server is running Fedora 10 (PPC). I can connect to the server from any Mac in the office, but I get permission errors when I try to save a file. Here is the relevant part of my `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/yearbook/svn">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location "/">
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/yearbook/svn/
    SVNAutoversioning on
    ModMimeUsePathInfo on
</Location>
```

I can manipulate files from the server, but I get permission errors when I try to save from a Mac. I tried following [these instructions](http://www.netmojo.ca/2007/05/03/subversion-webdav-osx/#solution), but to no avail. Even when they were enabled, the Mac still created the `.DS_Store` file. What really bothers me is that it will create a file I told it not to, but refuses to create a file I explicitly save.

A quick look in my error log shows many of these messages:

```
(2)No such file or directory: Anonymous lock creation is not allowed.  [401, #405]
```

Everyone needs access to the same things, so I am running the server without authentication. Do you think that this could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation, and some experimentation, I tried adding a username/password requirement to the server. Interestingly, it worked. it's not ideal, as I wanted it to be completely open, but it will work for now. Here's what I added to the `httpd.conf`:

```
<Location "/">
    # ...
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Yearbook Files"
    AuthUserFile /var/yearbook/yearbook-svn-auth
    Require valid-user
    # ...
</Location>
```

As a side question, does anyone know how to change the mount point of a WebDAV share on Mac OS X? Currently it shows up in Finder as the server's IP address, and I'd like a friendlier name displayed instead.

Answer (score 1):

For your "friendlier names" problem: If you have a local DNS running in the office and all clients configured to default to that domain name (the "Search Domains" preference in MacOS network preferences), clients can just connect to  http://server and the share will appear as server in the Finder. Without local DNS, you can do the same with entries in the /etc/hosts file for each client (just add an entry like

```
192.168.1.10    server
```

into it).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about that. I'll try it in the morning to see how well it works.

Comment: +1 Thank you! It shows up correctly now. I found an app that will mount the drives automatically with a username/password combo, so it's totally seamless to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the owner and group of the repository to the user under which apache is running